# How To Use Doctrine In symfony2 AbstractType

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to use doctrine in asymfony2 form type.

In services.yml I have:

```
fyp_user.profile.form.type:
    class: FYP\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType
    arguments: 
        - fos_user.model.user.class
        - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: fyp_user_profile }
```

My class looks like:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class ProfileFormType extends AbstractType
{
    private $em;
    private $session;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em; 
    }
```

I'm to do something like:

```
 $cust =  $this->em->getRepository('MyBundle:Customers')->findOneByEmail($email);
```

I keep getting

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to FYP\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, string given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/upgrade/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 3594
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mismatch between service definition and class constructor. In service definition you have two arguments: `fos_user.model.user.class` and `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager` and your constructor accepts only one (`EntityManager`). Just remove first entry from your `arguments` list in service definition and you'll be good